# How can I filter an array by multiple conditions but keeping its current state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to work on a filter functionality where I have 4 different filters and I need to have the option to combine them.

This is the data sample:

```
[
  {
    uniqueId: 23,
    status: false,
    employeeRole: true,
  },
  {
    uniqueId: 35,
    status: true,
    employeeRole: true,
  },
  {
    uniqueId: 9,
    status: true,
    employeeRole: false,
  }
]
```

The filters are: If the status `false === 'inactive'` || `true === 'active'` and the same for the employeeRole `true === 'APA'` || `false === 'employee'`.

The filter works only in one scenario. If I want to filter only by `status` or only by `employeeRole` it works but if I want both then one of the filters take over the other.

```
handleTableFilters = dataArray => {
    const { isActive, isAPA, isInactive, isEmployee } = this.props;

    const newArr = dataArray
      ? dataArray.filter(item => {
          if (isActive || isAPA || isInactive || isEmployee) {
            return (
              (isActive === true && item.statusDetail === true) ||
              (isInactive === true && item.statusDetail === false) ||
              (isAPA === true && item.employeeRole === true) ||
              (isEmployee === true && item.employeeRole === false)
            );
          }

          return item;
        })
      : [];

    return newArr;
};
```

These 4 props `isActive, isAPA, isInactive, isEmployee` are only flags, like in a checkbox, if I check the checkbox for `status` filter then it sets `isActive = true`.

This is one scenario where it doesn't work:
1 - Set filter to show only the `status === true` (it shows only `status true` as expected).

2 - Also set filter to show `employeeRole === true` (it shows all of the `employeeRole === true` ignoring that the status filter was set to show `status === true`).

So in the scenario the filters should work together. Only `status === true` + `employeeRole == true`.

Comment: Can isActive, isAPA, isInactive or isEmployee be undefined? If not then Medit;s answer will work.

Comment: Hi @HMR the problem is that those are flags. So when I set them to `true` the filter should be applied.

Comment: But isActive and isInActive cannot both be true, same goes for isEmployee and isAPA. My question is are these filters optional so if they are undefined then that filter should not be applied.

Comment: Yes @HMR they could be `false` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't write such code, its very annoying to fix and unreadable, separate it

```
handleTableFilters = dataArray => {
    const { isActive, isAPA, isInactive, isEmployee } = this.props;

    const activeFilter = item => item.statusDetail === isActive
    const APAFilter = item => item.employeeRole === isAPA


    return dataArray.filter(activeFilter).filter(APAFilter)
};
```

Comment: from my understanding, the filters should be dynamic, not hardcoded in the function.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work, it sets a filters array with the values, what prop to check and what value the prop should be. Then it filters all false or undefined values out of filters.

Then, if any filter is true it will filter dataArray reducing the filters array to true or false for each item.

```
//set default value for dataArray
const handleTableFilters = (dataArray=[]) => {
  const {
    isActive,
    isAPA,
    isInactive,
    isEmployee,
  } = this.props;
  const filters = [
    [isActive, 'statusDetail', true],
    [isInactive, 'statusDetail', false],
    [isAPA, 'employeeRole', true],
    [isEmployee, 'employeeRole', false],
  ].filter(([val]) => val); //remove any where value is false or undefined
  //do not even filter if all are false
  if (filters.length) {
    return dataArray.filter(item =>
      filters.reduce(
        (result, [, prop, value]) =>
          result && item[prop] === value,
        true
      )
    );
  }
  return dataArray;
};
```